# ui-router $transitions.transitionOptions set reload true

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, transition

I need to figure out a way to ALWAYS fully reload routes.

In my case:
parent-state has child-state-1 and child-state-2
Following the url parent-state/child-state-1 will trigger the execution of parent-state, making the wanted api calls, which child-state-1 takes some information from. **But** if I swtich from state-child-1 to state-child-2,
the parent state will be retained and the api calls will not be made again, **thus state-child-2 will have the wrong information**.

This dependency was made in order to avoid duplicate api calls and also to allow template iheritance.

I have found out that adding **ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}"** will reload my state, which is perfect, **but if I use the back/forward buttons on my browser/mouse the parent-state is retained** which screws up stuff.

So then i searched some more and found out that [this](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html#reload) is my solution, adding reload true to the transition options.

I figured out that it mihgt has to be placed in the run block because there I i do the auth check. So if that alters the state transition, I sould be able to force reload there.

My run block is:

```
run.$inject = ['$uiRouter', '$state', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$http', '$transitions', '$trace'];

    function run($uiRouter, $state, $cookies, $rootScope, $http, $transitions, $trace) {
        var pluginInstance = $uiRouter.plugin(Visualizer);

        $trace.enable('TRANSITION');

        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};

        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $rootScope.globals.currentUser.token_type + ' ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.access_token;
        }

        //Redirect to login if not authenticated before any transition
        $transitions.onStart({
            to: function(state) {
                // if state name is login or register
                if (state.name === 'login' || state.name === 'register'){
                    // break out of the redirect because auth not needed
                    return false;
                } else{
                    //continue to redirect
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }, function(trans) {
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (!loggedIn) {
                return trans.router.stateService.transitionTo('login');
            }
        });
    }
```

I haven't figure out a proper way to do it so i am asking for your help.

My guess is that somewhere I need to add something like:
**$state.transitionTo($staste.current.name, {$stateParams}, {reload: true})**
as i need to not overwrite the state params.